# How do you add custom mediators to the eclipse palette when developing an API in WSO2 Developer Studio?

Tags: wso2-integration-studio

I am trying to customize the palette in eclipse to include items for custom mediators that I have written.  I have tried digging through the tooling source, but am unable to find the location of these configurations.

[Palette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XTDJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Developer Studio is written on the [Eclipse GMF](https://www.eclipse.org/gmf-tooling/) framework. And, its properties view is implemented using the [Eclipse EEF](https://www.eclipse.org/eef/#/) framework. If we want to add a mediator onto the palette, we have to add its configuration into the [ecore](https://github.com/wso2/devstudio-tooling-esb/blob/master/plugins/org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.gmf.esb/model/esb.ecore) model, and generate respective models and codebase, accordingly. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265557/setup-a-custom-mediator-to-the-wso2-developer-studio-palette/55700898#55700898), for more details.