# Setup a custom mediator to the WSO2 Developer Studio palette

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio

Is possible to add a built custom mediator to the WSO2 Developer Studio palette?

The idea is avoid the error: **Unkown synapse configuration tag, At line X.** when i trying to edit an API or Proxy that has the reference in its sequence.

I am using WSO2 EI Tooling version 6.3.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to add a custom mediator into WSO2 Developer Studio. However, this requires quite a lot of implementation for both [wso2-synapse](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse) and [devstudio-tooling-esb](https://github.com/wso2/devstudio-tooling-esb), as WSO2 Developer Studio has been developed on top of the [Eclipse GMF](https://www.eclipse.org/gmf-tooling/) framework adhering to the ecore model.

[This](https://github.com/wso2/devstudio-tooling-esb/pull/690) is a custom mediator implementation, which had been incorporated into Developer Studio recently.